# Why function (+) matches type (a -> b -> b)?

Tags: haskell

fold function :

```
fold :: b -> (a -> b -> b) -> [a] -> b
fold z f []     = z
fold z f (x:xs) = f x (fold z f xs)
```

taken from http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/lectures/04-higher-order.html

```
Prelude> :t (+)
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a

*Main> fold (0) (+) [1,2,3]
6
```

What does type `(a -> b -> b)`  match with type `a -> a -> a` for `(+)` function ?

As fold definition accepts function type `(a -> b -> b)` this means the first 2 parameters `(a -> b)` are required to be of different types ?

Comment: Just because `a` and `b` are different letters doesn't mean that `a /= b`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, all it means is that `a` and `b` ***can*** be different, but it isn't mandatory for it to be different. In your case, it is the same.

A much simpler example to convey the point:

```
data SomeType a b = Test a b deriving (Show)
```

Now in `ghci`:

```
λ> :t Test
Test :: a -> b -> SomeType a b
λ> let x = Test (3 :: Int) (4 :: Int)
λ> :t x
x :: SomeType Int Int
```

Comment: `pair :: a -> b -> (a,b)` might be even simpler than a `data` example.

Answer (score 3):

You are thinking in reverse direction. You do not have to check whether `+` is identical or matches `a -> b -> b`, you want the type of `+` to be a *specialization* of `a -> b -> b` and to check this you have to *unify* the types.

Unification means that you want to see whether the type of `+` and the type `a -> b -> b` can be made equal by *renaming the type variables*.

So `+` has type `Num x => x -> x -> x`. Let's ignore the class constraint for now, and let's see if we can match the functional types.
The types become `x -> x -> x` and `a -> b -> b`. In fact it's better if we look at them as they really are, without using associativity: `x -> (x -> x)` and `a -> (b -> b)`.

The `->` is a *type constructor*. I.e. it is a function that maps a certain number of types to a different type. In this case the `->` constructor maps two types `t_1` and `t_2` to the functional type `(->) t_1 t_2` (which is usually denoted by `t_1 -> t_2`).

So the type `x -> (x -> x)` is actually `(->) x ((->) x x)` which is the type constructor `->` applied to `x` and to the type constructor `->` applied to `x` and `x`.
The other type is `(->) a ((->) b b)`.

When unifying you consider the outermost type constructor for the two types (`->` for both in this case). If this doesn't match, you cannot unify.
Otherwise you have to unify the arguments of the constructor.

So we have to unify `x` with `a`. They are both type variables, so we can *rename* one of them. Let's say that we rename `a` with `x`. So now we apply the renaming to the types, obtaining: `(->) x ((->) x x)` and `(->) x ((->) b b)` and you see that `x` and `x` now match.

Let's consider the second argument. It's not a type variable so we have to match the type constructor, and this is again `->` for both. So we procede recursively on the arguments.

We want to match `x` and `b`. They are both type variables, so we can rename one of them. Say we rename `x` to `b`. We apply this substitution to the types, obtaining: `(->) b ((->) b b)` and `(->) b ((->) b b)`. Now the everything matches. Hence the two types unify.

Regarding the class constraint, when we rename `x` with `b` we applied the substitution to the constraint too so `Num x` became `Num b` and the two final types are both `Num b => b -> b -> b`.

I hope this gave you some better understanding on how the types work and how the types are checked.

---

Side note: This is what haskell does when performing type inference. It first assign to an unknown function a fresh type variable `t`. Then it uses unification to obtain the type of the expression that defines it and check what type was associated with `t`, and this is the type of the function.

Comment: I think this is getting a bit too mechanical with the type constructors. A conceptional example (i.e. what gets unified with what) would be useful to have before the example of how the unification process operates.